# Angularjs reset radio input if clicked twice in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following jQuery click event that I am trying to "angularize" with an *ng-click* but can't really figure out how.

```
$('body').on('click change', 'input[type="radio"]:not([disabled])', function(event) {
    $(this).prop('checked') //if checked
    ? $(this).prop('checked',false).data('waschecked', false)   //uncheck
    : $(this).prop('checked',true).data('waschecked', true);    //else check
});
```

The goal is to check if the item is, indeed, already selected, and if it does, reset the radio button.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not use a checkbox rather than trying to override native functionality?

Comment: @tymeJV i don't want more than one option selected. But I want the user to have the ability to un-select their option if they change their mind and don't want to select an option

Comment: Then disable the checkboxes, or use logic to uncheck the other boxes, it'll be easier than trying to override native functionality. If you're still deadset - the `ngModel` for radios is bound to the `value` attribute, so assigning that / clearing it will clear the selection.

Comment: @bryan Does my answer solve this for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is non-standard behavior, but here is an example that does what you're looking for: https://jsbin.com/sicuhugevu/1/edit?html,js,output

For those who don't want to visit JSBin:

The JS:

```
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.radios = {
      selected: null,
      last: null
    };

    $scope.radioClick = function(event) {
      if ($scope.radios.last === $scope.radios.selected) {
        $scope.radios.selected = null;
        $scope.radios.last = null;

        return;
      }

      $scope.radios.last = event.target.value;
    };
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="test">
  <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="1"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="2"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="3"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 3</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the local version:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.radios = {
      selected: null,
      last: null
    };
  
    $scope.radioClick = function(event) {
      if ($scope.radios.last === $scope.radios.selected) {
        $scope.radios.selected = null;
        $scope.radios.last = null;
        
        return;
      }
      
      $scope.radios.last = event.target.value;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="test">
  <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="1"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="2"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" value="3"
                  data-ng-click="radioClick($event)"
                  data-ng-model="radios.selected">Option 3</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have lots of radio groups so I am not sure if this will work for my use case.

Comment: I'm sure it could be refactored to work with many radio groups. However, as everyone has said, this is not normal behavior for radio buttons. That's why you'll have to deal with extra work like this.

Comment: I don't know, my 4 lines of jQuery code seem to work just fine

Comment: Then stick with the jQuery code! Simpler is always better.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here is to use one value for the group state and a different value for the buttons, and use `ng-click` to compare the buttons to the group state.

for example:

```
<input type="radio" ng-checked="true" ng-model="buttons" value="one" ng-click="radioChanged()">
<input type="radio" ng-checked="false" ng-model="buttons" value="two" ng-click="radioChanged()">
<input type="radio" ng-checked="false" ng-model="buttons" value="three" ng-click="radioChanged()">

$scope.radioChanged = function (){
    if ($scope.buttons === $scope.group){
        $scope.buttons = undefined;
    }
    $scope.group = $scope.buttons;
    console.log($scope.group, $scope.buttons);
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lh9XjWr1cCxdf1asuKxo?p=preview

Comment: There could be an infinite amount of groups of radio buttons so this won't work for me. There isn't always going to just be one set of radio buttons on the page and it's impossible to tell how many there will be.

Comment: there is never "infinite" amounts of items in your UI.  You might not know at design time how many you have, but at runtime, you most definitely should know how many you have; it's unlikely you don't have data for a button you are going to put on the screen.  It really sounds like you are trying to turn this into an XY problem, if you can't quantify what you are trying to represent.

Comment: for each group you have, set the `ng-model` the same for that group; if necessary, pass the name of the group as a parameter to the `radioChanged` function.