# Find out if radio option is checked before it was clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following radio group.

```
<input type="radio" name="GROUP1" ng-checked="true" ng-model="group1" id="name1" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="GROUP1" ng-checked="false" ng-model="group1" id="name2" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="GROUP1" ng-checked="false" ng-model="group1" id="name3" value="three">
```

When a radio input is clicked, I want to be able to figure out if, before it was clicked, if it originally active or not.

For example, if I clicked on `#name1`, it would respond back true because it was already checked.

If I clicked on `#name3`, it would respond back false because `#name1` was originally selected. But if I click on `#name3` again, it would return back true.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: put watch on your model

Comment: @kram watch does not work because technically on the second click, the model variable does not change so the watch does not get called

Comment: as I was saying in the other question you asked regarding watchers, you still haven't really described what it is you are actually needing.  I understand that you want to know if someone clicked the same radio button twice, but why does that really even matter? also, why couldn't you just have a tandem variable that holds the current enabled option and check against that, if you *really* need to know?

Comment: I want to be able to clear the radio box if it is checked twice. I know this isn't the normal function or a radio box but I need to allow the user to be able to choose not to answer a grouped radio option question if they decided not to. And sometimes this happens after they choose an option. @Claies

Comment: Ok, so now we are getting to what you *really* want... You don't care about the click, you want a way to deselect a button in a group without selecting a different one.  That is logic that makes sense.  I knew there was an XY question hidden here...

Comment: Yea sorry @Claies. Sometimes I look at my problems in steps and don't think it all the way through when asking

Comment: it happens, the main thing is now you have a direction to take on a question that seems like it would have a practical answer

Comment: @claies [I did.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254513/angularjs-reset-radio-input-if-clicked-twice-in-a-row/31255795?noredirect=1#comment50539531_31255795). Just didn't get a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch this code in your controller.
Now, whenever your model will be changed(in the ui or in the controller), this event will be raised.

```
$scope.$watch('group1', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   //Place your code here ...
   // You have access to the old and to the new Value
});
```

Just for your information, try to use at least watches as you can...

Comment: watch does not work because technically on the second click, the model variable does not change so the watch does not get called

Answer (score -1):

js:

```
 if(this.checked){

   alert("selected");

}else{

  this.checked=true;
}
```

put this code in a function and call it in onClick event of radio button