# $watchCollection find out what part of array changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have an input box with the data attached to an array.

```
<input ng-model="data.input1" value="" />
```

I am trying to determine when data in my array has changed so I have the following:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newCol, oldCol, scope) {
    console.log(newCol, oldCol, scope);
});
```

However, I am trying to figure out what particular part of my array has changed, aka `data.input1` in this case.

If I had another input with `ng-model="data.input2"`, I'd like to know what *input2* was actually changed and not *input1*

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: your question doesn't really explain what you are trying to do or why you need `$watchCollection`, but in my experience, in most cases, relying on `$watch` or `$watchCollection` statements usually is an indication that you aren't aware of some way you can leverage a feature angular already has to do whatever you are trying.  I've only found a few cases where code couldn't be refactored to remove manual watchers.

Comment: @claies [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273261/find-out-if-radio-option-is-checked-before-it-was-clicked) is what I am trying to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's no "out of the box" way to figure out which part of the array changed. You'd need to loop through newCol and compare with oldCol values at each index:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newCol, oldCol) {
  for (var i = 0; i < newCol.length; i++) {
    if (newCol[i] !== oldCol[i]) {
      // newCol[i] is your changed value
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$watch` and need to set the third parameter as `true`. The third parameter is used to enable object equality.

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newCol, oldCol) {. . . },true);
```

And refer the below link for more information on using `$watch` with object equality.
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: I still don't see how I can figure out which part of the object was edited